# How to exclude last 3 characters of post code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to show the delivery postcode showing the first 4 digits of a postcode eg: WC4 5, So want to exclude last 3 characters from post code and by number of deliveries each post code by week like week 1 , week 2 for march. This is my query

```
  SELECT

  [Post Code]

  ,[Order Date]


  FROM [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Skids $Orders]

  where [Country]='united kingdom' and 
 [Order Date] >= '2017-03-01T00:00:00.000' AND 
 [Order Date] <= '2017-03-06T00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Use `left([Post Code], 4)` for the first 4 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you want to always exclude the last three characters. If you want everything up to the first character after the space, it depends on whether the second portion is always 4 characters.

```
select substring([Post Code],1,(len([Post Code])-3)) as trimmed_post_code
,[Post Code]
,[Order Date] 
FROM [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Skids $Orders]    
where [Country]='united kingdom' and 
[Order Date] >= '2017-03-01T00:00:00.000' AND 
[Order Date] <= '2017-03-06T00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple left clause should do:

```
SELECT  left([Post Code], len([Post Code]) - 3) as [Post Code]
        ,[Order Date]
FROM [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Skids $Orders]
where [Country]='united kingdom' and 
[Order Date] >= '2017-03-01T00:00:00.000' AND 
[Order Date] <= '2017-03-06T00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: but the problem is, I have show 4 charterers always eg: we11 ( for we11 2ng) and wc1 4 (for wc1 4lx) so 4 characters always must be in the report. when I apply -3 it's showing 3 charecters where post code is wc1 4lx. Please help.

Comment: Do the spaces need to be maintained in the output i.e. does it matter if it is "wc14" vs. "wc1 4" (for wc1 4lx)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks ,solved with out spaces. Used replace and sub string .